# One to One chat application in java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, chat, cometd

Hi Im planning to create a one to one chat application in Spring2/hibernate without using XMPP/Jabber and need to run in websphere server.

Can someone point me some technology to use to create comunication channel between two users

Is CometD a good option?will it run on websphere?

Comment: Although this might be a good question i do not think StackOverflow is a right place to ask it

Answer (score 2):

CometD is a good option and it should run on websphere however it works best on Jetty as there are optimizations in place for it.  CometD 3 will have support for jsr-356 javax.websocket so I would recommend using a websphere version that supports that since you are starting out with it...or just use Jetty. :)